# MVC3 Action link on layout navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am writing one of my first MVC3 web applications. I have my navigation coded like so in my SiteLayout.cshtml.

```
<table width="950" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 40px;">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>@Html.ActionLink( 
                    "Home", 
                    "Index", 
                    null, 
                    new { @class= "link1"}) 
                </td>
                <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/img3.gif")" alt="" width="2" height="40" /></td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink( 
                    "Events", 
                    "Events", 
                    null, 
                    new { @class= "link1"}) 
                </td>
                <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/img3.gif")" alt="" width="2" height="40" /></td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink( 
                    "Membership", 
                    "Membership", 
                    null, 
                    new { @class= "link1"}) 
                </td>
                <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/img3.gif")" alt="" width="2" height="40" /></td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink( 
                    "Photos", 
                    "Photos", 
                    null, 
                    new { @class= "link1"} )
                </td>
                <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/img3.gif")" alt="" width="2" height="40" /></td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink( 
                    "About Us", 
                    "AboutUS", 
                    null, 
                    new { @class= "link1"})
                </td>
                <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/img3.gif")" alt="" width="2" height="40" /></td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink( 
                    "Contact Us", 
                    "ContactUs", 
                    null, 
                    new { @class= "link1"})</td>
            </tr>
        </table>``
```

Whenever I switch over to my second controller registration which uses the same layout.cshtml the result returned by the action link is

```
http://localhost:49365/registration/Photos
```

How would I make the action link point back to the Site controller even if it is currently on the registration controller? I have already tried putting "Site" where I currently have the null value. If I do that then it works correctly but displays this url

```
http://localhost:49365/Site/Photos?class=link1
```

and the css class is no longer applied to the link. The url I'm hoping for is the same url

http://localhost:49365/site/photos

that would be displayed if I were using the link from my default site control. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Many Blessings,

Jared

Comment: as an offtopic tip, use CSS for the image in your view. this way you can avoid for each <img> tag to make a GET request to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a matter of overload resolution. The list of all overloads can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx).

As written, you end up using the `HtmlHelper, string, string, object, object` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx), and your first `null` is the `routeValues`, and so the anonymous object is your `htmlAttributes`.

You're on the right track passing `"Site"` instead of `null` to get the right controller, but  this moves you to using the `HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx). The first object is still `routeValues`, which explains why it becomes a query string.

To specify `htmlAttributes`, you can continue passing a `null` placeholder for the `routeValues`

```
@Html.ActionLink( 
                "Photos", 
                "Photos",
                "Site", 
                null, 
                new { @class= "link1"} )
```

or you used [named arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

```
@Html.ActionLink( 
                "Photos", 
                "Photos",
                "Site", 
                htmlAttributes: new { @class= "link1"} )
```

Comment: Thank you this post directed me to understanding the overloads of the html helper ActionLink() much more thoroughly. What I wound up doing was the following.                                                             @Html.ActionLink(
                        "Contact Us",
                        "ContactUs",
                        new { controller = "Site" },
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "link1" })